# Cannot create work item control of type "MultiValueControl"

Tags: tfs-2015, codeplex

I have tried to install the latest version of the MultiValueContol for TFS 2015 update 3. I have it working when you are in Visual Studio. You can see the checkbox and it works. If I define the type as MultiValueControl (see test1 below) it works in VS but in the web I get an error message: Cannot create work item control of type "MultiValueControl"

I found an article that said define it as type=FieldControl and PreferedType=MultiValueControl.. (see test2 below)  This works on VS ok, but on web access it shows me the 2 entries I selected when I created the WIT in VS, but when you select it acts as a fieldcontrol and only allows me to choose one item in the list. Based on the earlier warning in the Web access page, the browser page can't load that control.?

I have tried the following xml configs.
Test1:

```
 <FIELD name="Technology Domain" refname="WPS.TechnologyDomain" type="String" reportable="dimension">
    <SUGGESTEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="[Item 1]" />
      <LISTITEM value="[item 2]" />
    </SUGGESTEDVALUES>
  </FIELD>
```

and
Test2:

```
 <FIELD name="Technology Domain" refname="WPS.TechnologyDomain" type="String" reportable="dimension">
    <SUGGESTEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="[Item 1]" />
      <LISTITEM value="[item 2]" />
    </SUGGESTEDVALUES>
  </FIELD>
```

I'm not sure what to check next.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using the extension [Custom Controls for TFS Work Item Tracking](https://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/). According to the responses from author :

> *@PatDelaney*, The latest version of the control refactored to support
> the new TFS "15". For TFS 2015 you should use the older version
> http://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/releases/view/620316. Let us
> know if this helps
>
> Reply by kabalas (Coordinator) at 5:11 AM

Please have a try with the old version as suggested.

Comment: Using that older version fixed my issue.  Thanks